# Why doesn't monit like this syntax

Tags: debian, monitoring, monit

I am trying to setup [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/) for my debian server. I have a main monitrc file in `/etc/monit` which at the end has `include /etc/monit/conf.d/*`.

In conf.d I have two files for my apache and mysql servers:

```
# ls -al /etc/monit/conf.d
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 15 16:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 15 16:02 ..
-rwx------ 1 root root  272 Apr 15 15:38 apache2.conf
-rwx------ 1 root root  264 Apr 15 15:47 mysql.conf
```

When I run `monit -t` (to test the configuration syntax) I get:

```
/etc/monit/conf.d/apache2.conf:1: Error: syntax error 'check process '
```

The same error occurs for the mysql configuration file if I delete/move the apache2.conf file.

```
# cat apache2.conf
check process apache2 with pidfile /var/run/apache2.pid
  start program = "/usr/sbin/service apache2 start"
  stop program = "/usr/sbin/service apache2 stop"
  if failed
    host localhost
    port 80
    protocol http
    request "/catalog/"
    then restart and alert
```

And the contents of `mysql.conf`

```
# cat mysql.conf


  check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    group database
    start program = "/usr/sbin/service mysqld start"
    stop program = "/usr/sbin/service mysqld stop"
    if failed host localhost port 3306 protocol mysql then restart and alert
```

I have:

- tried many variations of the conf file
- looked at the documentation 20 times over
- substituting in a mysqld.conf file from a [public repository of common monit config files](https://github.com/tolland/monit-shared/blob/master/monit.d/mysqld.conf) and removing the apache2 config file
- looked over the files in hex, there's no funny characters.
- tried both tabs and spaces.
- removing all but the first line.
- double-checked that `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` does indeed exist.
- made sure the permissions on both `monitrc` and both conf.d file are 0700.

At this point I am completely perplexed as to what could possibly be causing the (not very helpful) error message, `/etc/monit/conf.d/apache2.conf:1: Error: syntax error 'check process '`

Comment: It looks like you are not using any of the default locations for `monitrc`.  Did you run `monit -c insert_your_monitrc_path_here` before executing `monit -t`?

Comment: @TimothyMartin I just tried that, no change. Monit does seem to be finding the files, since it reports the location of them accurately and is able to read them.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today. I was able to track the issue down to a second monit config file. It appears as of 5.17.1 that if a config file does not close correctly that it will throw a syntax error immediately when it tries to load the next file.

In my case I had an alert that ended with `repeat every 10` and was missing the "cycles" after the number. Even though this file was invalid, it was causing a completely different file to appear as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, and don't know if it's related, but I'm not sure you can write `then restart and alert`.

Pretty sure `alert` is already an implicit as part of `restart` anyways and therefore not needed.